# How to refine list of methods/properties in autocomplete to the lowest subclass in Xcode

Tags: xcode

When I subclass a class, such as NSObject, and add my own properties/methods to the subclass, I get to see the properties/methods of all classes in the ancestor hierarchy in the autocomplete window. Is there any way to refine/limit it to properties/methods of the most recent (or lowest) subclass?

So, imagine a hierarchy like

```
NSObject > Class1 > Class2 > LatestClass

LatestClass *lc = [LatestClass new];
lc. should return only properties/methods from the LatestClass only
```